# How can I make a counter for every country using a loop? R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I think this is very easy but I have no idea how to do it (or how to search it).

Okay so I got 378 observations for a lot of countries.

It goes like this

```
ISO3C       Date     Country    Vaccines Tests Confirmed Recovered Death Hospitalized Ventilation ICU
1   AFG 2020-01-01 Afghanistan        0     0         0         0     0            0           0   0
2   AFG 2020-01-02 Afghanistan        0     0         0         0     0            0           0   0
3   AFG 2020-01-03 Afghanistan        0     0         0         0     0            0           0   0
4   AFG 2020-01-04 Afghanistan        0     0         0         0     0            0           0   0
5   AFG 2020-01-05 Afghanistan        0     0         0         0     0            0           0   0
```

So How do I set a counter that jan 1st 2020 is 1 till today (2021-01-12) that is day no. 378, and then start over if `Country` changes

and what if the first day isn't jan 1st, 2020, but each country has it own start date?

Comment: It would help if your example data had more than one country. But if you have complete observations (378) for each country then there's no need to "start over" by country? The counter is just Date - start Date. See the answer by @abdessabour-mtk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract the `first(Date)` from each country.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(ISO3C, Date) %>%
  group_by(ISO3C) %>% 
  mutate(counter = Date - first(Date) + 1) -> result

result
```

Comment: HOT DAMN! You won. It worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Actually grouping won't change anything but since you want it

```r
df %>% group_by(ISO3C) %>% mutate(counter= Date - as.Date("01-01-2020"))
```

this will work

```r
df %>% mutate(counter= Date - as.Date("01-01-2020"))
```

#### EDIT

```r
df %>% inner_join(df_origins) %>% mutate(counter= Date - Origin) %>% select(!Origin)
```

where `df_origins` has columns `Country` and `Origin`

Comment: you  can drop the `group_by`

Comment: Yes, but what if the first day isn't in jan 1st? how can i set the counter then? Every country has their own first day (now).

Comment: so you have it in another `data.frame` you can `inner_join` on country then subtract date from the `origin` date